# Evaluating particular sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please, how do I evaluate the following which came about in a larger problem.

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k   ~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k.$$

Comment: The approach of Dominic Michaelis is best, but if you are feeling in a formula mood (I am not), you can use the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series. For the second sum we get $\frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{1-(-1)}$. Love those minus signs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing up the sum for some $n$ gives you an idea what will be the result:
$$\sum_{k=1}^1 (-1)^k =-1$$ 
$$\sum_{k=1}^2 (-1)^k= -1+1=0$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^3 (-1)^k=-1+1-1=-1$$
And in the other case make the same.

Comment: One could look at this sum the way Gauss might; that is, by pairing up appropriate terms...

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^i = \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}(-1)^{2i}+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor}(-1)^{2i-1} = {\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}-{\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor}.$

If (say) $n = 2r$, then $ {\lfloor 2r/2 \rfloor}-{\lfloor (2r+1)/2 \rfloor} = r-r = 0.$ On the other hand:

If (say) $n = 2r+1$, then $ {\lfloor (2r+1)/2 \rfloor}-{\lfloor 2(r+1)/2 \rfloor} = r-(r+1) = -1.$